# Lines dividing graphs using layout() in R

Tags: r, layout, plot, line, margin

I'm using layout() in R to produce a series of 9 graphs (in a 3x3 layout)

```
    m <- rbind(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6), c(7,8,9))
    layout(m)
```

I'm trying to put 2 vertical lines between the three columns in order to separate the columns from each other. box() is not appropriate as I want the rows to be linked and so don't want lines there, and I'm struggling to find any help using line() function and any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you change the graphical parameters so that all plotting is clipped to the device region, and then add the vertical lines for separation afterwards using `abline()`? For example:

```
m <- rbind(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6), c(7,8,9))

# Clips drawing to the device region
# See ?par for more details of the argument
par(xpd=NA)

layout(m)

# Insert you nine plots here
for(i in 1:9) {
   plot(1,1)
}

# Check the correct coordinates with
# locator(), and the arguments
# accordingly. These are about right,
# if the plot region is rectangular.
abline(v=0.25)
abline(v=-1.06)
```

The resulting plot whould appear as below.

[image]

Comment: That's almost exactly what I need, however, each of my plots uses abline() to add lines to the individual plots. When I use this solution all of the abline's extent the full length of the "device"... Also, I have set par() for each of the individual graphs, and this par(xpd=NA) overrides that... Otherwise, what you have drawn above is exactly what I need.

Comment: Sorry, I just figured it out!! Thank you so much for this reply. I just needed to play around where par() goes!!

Answer (score 1):

Anothe option is to play with `layout`:

```
layout(rbind(c(1,10, 2,11,3),
             c(4,10, 5,11,6),
             c(7,10, 8,11,9)),
widths=c(1, lcm(3), 1,lcm(3),1),
respect=TRUE)

## you plot your 9 plots  
for(i in 1:9) {
  plot(1,1)
}
## you plot the separation 
plot(1,1,type='n',axes=FALSE, ann=FALSE)
## here I use a vertical line but you can plot anything (box, segments,..)
abline(v=1)

plot(1,1,type='n',axes=FALSE, ann=FALSE)
abline(v=1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`grconvertX` is an alternative to @JTT's suggestion to `locator` to find the line positions:

```
m <- rbind(c(1,2,3), c(4,5,6), c(7,8,9))
layout(m)
for(i in 1:9) {
   plot(1,1)
}
abline(v=grconvertX(1:2/3, 'ndc', 'user'))
```

[image]